# Tomcat: how to create a HttpRequestListener, similar to HttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-listeners

I have created a HttpSessionListener on my webapp, and its works fine. How can i create a similar request listener, called when a user make a request on a session? It is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`ServletRequestListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html). It is notified whenever a request is created and destroyed.

Note that "make are request on a session" does not make sense. The servlet container associates a session with a request based on the JSESSIONID passed with the request.

Comment: Thank you very much! ServletRequestListener is exactly what I want.

Comment: Another option is a `javax.servlet.Filter` whenever you actually want to listen on more specific request URL patterns.